# How to get Meteor spacebar id for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, meteor

```
<template name="server">
    <tr>
        <td class="column" id="checkBoxColumn"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "additionalInfo" id = {{this._id}}>
    </tr>
</template>
```

This is my template, and I am not sure what to put inside the jQuery function to retrieve the id = {{this._id}} from the template above. Thank you.

```
$(WhatGoesHere?).slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: Why not just use the `class`, since you're not using the `id` for anything specific anyway. `$(". additionalInfo").slideDown("slow");`

Comment: If I do that the slide down on click on one row, would work for all the rows. I was thinking if I used each unique id, then the on click for each row would perform a slide down on their respective row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get `id` of each row, you can simply use `$(this).slideDown()`. I made a quick example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8xw10sc/1/).

If you need more specific answer, you'll have to provide your HTML, what is being clicked and what should slide down.